# MAC OS Monterey Python Build Error: Python Quit Unexpectedly

Tags: python, build, compiler-errors, macos-monterey

How do I get past this build error? I have tried setting my build system to both python as well as python3 but the error is quite persistent. [Sublime text throwing an error while building.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeL5i.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I had both python 3.7 and 3.8 installed and had to change the path. It worked for me. I had previously installed anaconda which came with python 3.7 and also had manually installed 3.8 using Brew.

```
which python3.7
```

This gave me the path for 3.7

```
which python3.8
/Users/Marc/Environments/tiktok/bin/python3.8
```

This gave me the path for 3.8

Next up I copied the path from 3.8 and pasted it into

```
PATH="/Users/Marc/Environments/tiktok/bin/python3.8" 
export PATH
```

Restart your terminal.